# Ruby ++ not work?

Tags: ruby

Using Ruby, I can't seem to get the following to work:

```
a = 1
a++
```

The above line works in `irb` but doesn't work when I compile from file.

Is there anything I missed out? I'm using Ruby 2.0.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". How are you confirming it "doesn't work"?

Comment: maybe you need to learn ruby first?

Comment: Please don't use chat speak here, "thx" an the like are pretty much never appropriate to use on Stack Overflow.

Comment: And also it "doesn't work" in irb

Comment: OP probably thinks it works in irb because of this: `2.0.0-p0 :089 > a = 1
 => 1
2.0.0-p0 :090 > a++
2.0.0-p0 :091 >   a
 => 2`. So `a` seems to be 2, but what he really did was `a++a`. `a` itself was still 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby doesn't have `++` or `--` operators but `+=` and `-=` accomplish the same thing.  Try using the `+=` notation like this:

```
a = 1
a+= 1
  #=> 2
```

Here is a [good reference list](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm) of valid ruby operators.

Answer (score 8):

Ruby has no pre/post increment/decrement operator. For instance, `x++` or `x--` will fail to parse. More importantly, `++x` or `--x` will do nothing! In fact, they behave as multiple unary prefix operators: `-x == ---x == -----x == ......` To increment a number, simply write `x += 1`

Comment: `x++` is perfectly legal, when followed by another operand. It is parsed as `x + (+?)`. Remember that operands can be separated from the operators with whitespace, including newlines. So, `x++` on one line followed by `y` on the next line is perfectly valid and is the same as `x + +y` which is the same as `x.+(y.+@)`. That's why `x++` on its own appears to work in IRb: because IRb is waiting for the operand on the next line and will only throw an error *then*.